# Getting error a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have to read excel and if column value meet some condition i have to add some thing.
Below are the input excel
[image]

I just need to take Name and Values if Value > 50

Below is my script.

```
   df = pd.read_excel(file)
   print (df[df['Value'] > 50]) #prints the name and values 
   if df[df['Value'] > 50]:
       print (df['Value'])
```

I am getting ValueError.
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
Please help me.

Expected Output:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: Hi Guy, Actually i have seen the ans, but i can't find proper solution.

Comment: Do you need `df.loc[df['Value'] > 50, 'Name']` ? Because not sure if understand `if df[df['Value'] > 50]`, because like you test before `df[df['Value'] > 50]` return DataFrame. Or you need `if (df['Value'] > 50).any():` test if at least one >50 value in column `Value` ?

Comment: @jezrael, I tried with .any, .empty and .bool, but these methods comparing the whole Value column, but I need to take each and every Boolean expressions.

Comment: @MohanRaoD - What is expected output?

Comment: So you need `df1 = (df[df['Value'] > 50])` `print (df1)`?

Comment: @jezrael, yeah, Also, if condition must be there. I have to add some more functions and methods in if condition.

Comment: @MohanRaoD - Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

If want test at least one value `>50` before filtering by mask use `any` for scalar `True` or `False`:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file)

mask = df['Value'] > 50
if mask.any():
    df1 = df[mask]
    print (df1)
```

If `if` statement is not necessary:

```
df1 = df[df['Value'] > 50]
print (df1)
```

You can also check [using if truth statements with pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas).

Comment: Dear Andreson, thanks for your reply. But my requirement is without using the DOT (.any,.bool, .empty, .all ..etc) operator should run the if condition with each and every Boolean expression (True or False), Kindly advise do have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to print all the values greater than 50, do:

```
print(df[df['Value'] > 50].values)
```

Comment: OP write `I just need to take Name and Values if Value > 50`

Comment: what is `print (df[df['Value'] > 50])` in his answer

Comment: Yes, exactly, If i want to use if condition then? Any solution?